# How can I have the bones of my armature find the most direct path when reseting their rotation?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

My character does a backflip and therefore the hip and abdomen bones have been rotated "360" degrees. Considering that the idle pose hasn't made these transformations if the end of the backflip animation were to be meshed back into the idle pose; the abdomen and hip bones would need to revert themselves by taking the long way around (i.e. rotate -"360" degrees) to reach their original orientation.

I tacked on a keyframe from the beginning of the animation to the end as a sample of what I assume would happen:
[image: character flipping then returning to it's original rotation]

Is there any way to have the bones ignore the specifics of their original rotation to make a direct transition without needing to include a jump between two frames where I flip all the rotations manually? 
(I think that would disturb the physics if i did add a 1 frame jump to reset the rotations anyways) 
Or am I going about this wrong and there happens to be an option for this issue when animation meshing?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I would try some workarounds, like having your backflip rotate from - 360 to 0, or create a copy of the idle in which the hip bones have a 360 rot vaue. But maybe a real Pro has a better answer!

Comment: Actually the workaround doesn't seem to work at all. There doesn't seem to be any reference for the bones' rotation relative to their origin. I think that there's an extra layer to this whole thing that only counts transformations made throughout the tweening process and the armature itself isn't relevant to the path of the transforms.

Comment: manually rotating the bones -360 in the span of one frame doesn't work but If I Alt-R it does act as if I've reset the rotation of this "extra layer" of the pose that determines the origins.
---

so what i have to do for each of these bones to implement this workaround is:

**1)** copy the rotation values from the bone in it's original pose. (i had to paste them into notepad, I'll need to activate the Copy Attributes Menu Addon to do this faster) 
**2)** Alt-R (reset the bone)
**3)** paste the copied rotation values back into the bone and flip the negatives and positives.

Comment: Nvm, the "Copy Attributes Menu Addon" doesn't help with this and i need to manually copy and paste these values into and out of a notepad.  :(